# HTML5: Canvas Context fillText/strokeText does not draw

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am following a tutorial from [Dev.Opera](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/) about HTML5 Painting application and trying to improve it by adding a text tool that prompts user of what text they wanted to input after clicking on coordinate.

E.g. User clicked on coordinate 100,200 , a prompt will ask what text they wanted to show and after user entered the text, it should draw it on canvas.

I knew my browser support canvas fillText and strokeText function, because when I load [this web](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_canvas_tut_text2) the text shows.

On the tutorial I follow, Dev.Opera creates a temp canvas on the real canvas so that images (shapes and text) are supposedly drawn to temp canvas and then transferred to real canvas by img_update() method.

```
// This function draws the #imageTemp canvas on top of #imageView,
// after which #imageTemp is cleared. This function is called each time when the
// user completes a drawing operation.
function img_update () {
  contexto.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

I tried to do fillText on context like this:

```
context.fillText(textVar, x, y);
img_update();
```

and this does not draw the text, while:

```
contexto.fillText(textVar, x, y);
```

draws it perfectly.
I had expand the program to draw circle, polyline, and fills and all of them works perfectly on the context without having to draw them at contexto.

How can I force the text to be drawn at context and then transfer it using img_update()?

Comment: maybe fill style is set so that you donot see the text? a sample code on jsbin or somewhere would help.

Comment: maybe [this](http://jsbin.com/ewekoh/2/) would help?

Comment: when I tried contexto.fillText, I did not change any settings on the fill. So it should not be a fill style problem @akonsu

Comment: Yes, I confirmed @akonsu is correct using your jsbin.  If you add ctx.fillStyle="orange" just before your fillText, your text will correctly draw.

Comment: Ahh, That's right. Initial Fill was white with alpha 0 so it does not draw. Could you or akonsu please answer this question so I could upvote one of you guys properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe fill style is set so that you do not see the text?